# python using ctypes to work with dll - structure OUT argument

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

In the header file of the dll I have the following structure

```
typedef struct USMC_Devices_st{
DWORD NOD;          // Number of the devices ready to work

char **Serial;      // Array of 16 byte ASCII strings
char **Version;     // Array of 4 byte ASCII strings
} USMC_Devices;         // Structure representing connected devices
```

I would like to call a dll function:
DWORD USMC_Init( USMC_Devices &Str );

I tried with this:

```
class USMCDevices(Structure):
   _fields_ = [("NOD", c_long),
            ("Serial", c_char_p),
            ("Version", c_char_p)]

usmc = cdll.USMCDLL #this is the dll file
init = usmc.USMC_Init
init.restype = c_int32; # return type
init.argtypes = [USMCDevices]; # argument
dev = USMCDevices()
init(dev)
```

I get an error here. I guess the problem is with "Serial" and "Version" which both are array corresponding to the NOD (number of devices).

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

I really appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `POINTER(c_char_p)` for the `char **` pointers. Indexing `Serial` or `Version` creates a Python string for the given null-terminated string. Note that indexing in the array beyond `NOD - 1` either produces garbage values or will crash the interpreter.

C:

```c
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct USMC_Devices_st {
    DWORD NOD;       // Number of the devices ready to work
    char **Serial;   // Array of 16 byte ASCII strings
    char **Version;  // Array of 4 byte ASCII strings
} USMC_Devices;

char *Serial[] = {"000000000000001", "000000000000002"};
char *Version[] = {"001", "002"};

__declspec(dllexport) DWORD USMC_Init(USMC_Devices *devices) {

    devices->NOD = 2;
    devices->Serial = Serial;
    devices->Version = Version;

    return 0;
}

// build: cl usmcdll.c /LD
```

Python:

```python
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

class USMCDevices(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("NOD", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("Serial", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)),
                ("Version", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))]

usmc = ctypes.cdll.USMCDLL
init = usmc.USMC_Init
init.restype = wintypes.DWORD
init.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(USMCDevices)]
dev = USMCDevices()
init(ctypes.byref(dev))

devices = [dev.Serial[i] + b':' + dev.Version[i]
           for i in range(dev.NOD)]
print('\n'.join(d.decode('ascii') for d in devices))
```

Output:

```
000000000000001:001
000000000000002:002
```

Comment: Thank you very very much!!!
You have helped me a lot!!
However, I still have a problem. The the pointer of dev.Serial[i].value does not point to the correct location. For example: I get a proper serial string at dev.Serial[2].value while at index i=0 or i=1 I get wrong data (the size of the array is only two). Any ideas???

Comment: Additionally: If I change the Structure to and define first Version and then Serial, then the string is at dev.Serial[1] and all other indexes give wrong results. I would really appreciate a hint!

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now!!! Other functions are also working now. You have helped me a lot! Thank you and I wish you a nice day!!!